# Laravel 5.7 - Users/followers pivot table to create a follower (user) to Bug relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, pivot-table, laravel-5.7

This app has a Bug model and a User model. Users can "follow" Bugs. This seems like a pivot table. What's the simplest way to implement this with a migration and Model relationship? I'm thinking along the lines of a followers table:

```
    Schema::create('followers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->uuid('bug_id');
        $table->uuid('user_id');
        $table->index(['bug_id', 'user_id']);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

Where I'm mostly stumped is the followers relationship in the Bugs Model. This is where I'm currently at:

```
public function followers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'followers', 'bug_id', 'user_id');;
}
```

This really doesn't seem right. New to eloquent pivot tables, so really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a many-to-many relationship which requires an intermediary table `bug_follower` just as you created one and you also need to create a relationship from `Bug` to `Follower` as you did, but also create the relationship from `Follower` to `Bugs`. You are on the right track.

Overall you will have 2 models: `Bug`, `Follower`.

You will also have 3 tables: `bugs`, `followers`, `bug_follower`

And 2 relationships from `Bug` and `Follower` to each other

---

**EDIT**: This is how your relationship needs to look like:

```
public function followers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'followers', 'bug_id', 'user_id');
}
```

You can check more about subject in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Comment: I updated my question with where I'm currently at with this. I have a Bug model and a User model and I created a followers table that links the two.